# Split string in JavaScript using a regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regex for use in javascript.

```
var script = "function onclick() {loadArea('areaog_og_group_og_consumedservice', '\x26roleOrd\x3d1');}";
var match = new RegExp("'[^']*(\\.[^']*)*'").exec(script);
```

I would like split to contain two elements:

```
match[0] == "'areaog_og_group_og_consumedservice'";

match[1] == "'\x26roleOrd\x3d1'";
```

This regex matches correctly when testing it at gskinner.com/RegExr/ but it does not work in my Javascript.  This issue can be replicated by testing ir here http://www.regextester.com/.

I need the solution to work with Internet Explorer 6 and above.

Can any regex guru's help?

Comment: Can you describe the behavior you are experiencing? Does it match at all? or just match the wrong section?

Comment: I'm getting the first match but second one appeared to be empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex you're looking for is `.*?('[^']*')\s*,\s*('[^']*')`. The catch here is that, as usual, `match[0]` is the entire matched text (this is very normal) so it's not particularly useful to you. `match[1]` and `match[2]` are the two matches you're looking for.

```
var script = "function onclick() {loadArea('areaog_og_group_og_consumedservice', '\x26roleOrd\x3d1');}";
var parameters = /.*?('[^']*')\s*,\s*('[^']*')/.exec(script);
alert("you've done: loadArea("+parameters[1]+", "+parameters[2]+");");
```

The only issue I have with this is that it's somewhat inflexible. You might want to spend a little time to match function calls with 2 or 3 parameters?

**EDIT**
In response to you're request, here is the regex to match 1,2,3,...,n parameters. If you notice, I used a non-capturing group (the `(?: )` part) to find many instances of the comma followed by the second parameter.

```
/.*?('[^']*')(?:\s*,\s*('[^']*'))*/
```

Comment: Thanks for reply and the  heads up on ignoring the first match. This meet's the questions requirement, thank you. I should of also specified that sometime there's only one parameter in the script.  Are you able to tweek it to allow for that please?

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your regex, it looks like you're trying to match a single-quoted string that may contain escaped quotes.  The correct form of that regex is:

```
'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'
```

(If you *don't* need to allow for escaped quotes, `/'[^']*'/` is all you need.)  You also have to set the `g` flag if you want to get both strings.  Here's the regex in its regex-literal form:

```
/'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'/g
```

If you use the RegExp constructor instead of a regex literal, you have to double-escape the backslashes: once for the string literal and once for the regex.  You also have to pass the flags (`g`, `i`, `m`) as a separate parameter:

```
var rgx = new RegExp("'[^'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^'\\\\]*)*'", "g");
while (result = rgx.exec(script))
    print(result[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I seem to get the first match but the second one is undefined, I tried this at http://www.regextester.com/ 

matches: 0: ('areaog_og_group_og_consumedservice')
1: (undefined)

Comment: That `1:` refers to the contents of the first capturing group; it came out as `undefined` because that part of the regex didn't participate in the match.  As a matter of fact, there shouldn't even *be* a first capturing group; I meant to use a non-capturing group like I did in the other regexes. (I'll fix that.)  If you want to match two or more strings, you have to call `exec()` repeatedly as I demonstrated.

Comment: Arh, ok, I didn't realise that you could call exec multiple times.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
'([^']*)'\s*,\s*'([^']*)'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this works thank you. I should of also specified that sometime there's only one parameter in the script